# Super Search Plural Not Working When Multiple Keywords are Used

Tags: supersearch

I am using Solspace Super Search version 2.2.4 on EE v2.9.0, and found an issue with its fuzzy/plural search.

Searching a single plural word, e.g. "rods" will show results for products with "rod" in it. Searching "fibreglass rod" will show products with "fibreglass rod" in it. Searching "fibreglass rods" (so two words, plural rods) shows No Results.

The expected results is to show all products with "fibreglass rod" in it.

So it seems that plurals do not work when in multiple words. I do not want to search ANY words as results without fibreglass will be shown.

Is there a solution?

**Search Form**

```
{exp:super_search:search}
<form action="{path='search'}/" method="post" id="search-form" class="search-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{XID_HASH}" /> <!-- Important! --> 
    <input
        type="text"
        name="keywords"
        id="search"
        value="{super_search_keywords}"
        placeholder="Search something here..." title="To search for a phrase, place the words inside double quotes. To search for entries without certain words or phrases, place a negative sign (-) before it."
    />
</form>
{/exp:super_search:search}
```

**Results**

```
{exp:super_search:results search_in="title|sku|product_summary|product_description|product_keywords|content_intro" channel="products|made_to_measure|content|blog|gallery|team|videos|testimonials"
 orderby="channel_name+custom+'products,made_to_measure,content,blog,gallery,team,videos,testimonials'"}

{title}

{/exp:search_fields}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not be the answer you would like to hear...

But I would recommend changing your search module to [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search) and rewriting your template code to use this instead.

*Low Search* makes use of [filters](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters) allowing you to customise the intelligence behind your keyword searches. **keywords:inflect** is the filter option that will enable you to do what you are describing above.

There is a nice example on their website on how to use it:
http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/examples#keywords

*Super Search* by Solspace has long been discontinued and when they did support it, the list of bugs and odd quirks was a mile long. No wonder they had the sense to finally drop the product

Comment: I kind of agree as Solspace abandoned SuperSearch anyway. Which is sad as I always thought it was one of their flagship products.

Comment: Already tried it and had other issues that were greater than the issue above!